# Arduino Yun RFID-RC522 module not working

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-yun, rfid

I have tried to use Arduino Uno with RFID-RC522 module. It is good work[1] and read rfid cards. But Arduino Yun doesn't work with RFID-RC522 module.

What is diffrent Uno and Yun?

1- http://www.grantgibson.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-get-started-with-the-mifare-mf522-an-and-arduino/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the link you provided, we can see that the RFID-RC522 uses SPI to communicate with Arduino.

On Arduino UNO, the SPI pins are located as follows:

- pin 11: MOSI,
- pin 12: MISO,
- pin 13: SCK

On the Arduino YUN, this is different though; as stated [there](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun) (bold highlight is mine):

> SPI: on the ICSP header. These pins support SPI communication using
>   the SPI library. **Note that the SPI pins are not connected to any of**
>   **the digital I/O pins as they are on the Uno**, They are only available
>   on the ICSP connector. This means that if you have a shield that uses
>   SPI, but does NOT have a 6-pin ICSP connector that connects to the
>   Yún's 6-pin ICSP header, the shield will not work.

Hence you can not wire the RFID-RC522 module the same on UNO and Yun.
For the Yun, you'll have to follow this wiring picture:

[image]

Pin 1 in image above is the pin that is marked with a dot on the Yun PCB.

Also see the ISP-header layout, at the lower-right corner of the [yun_by_pighi](http://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-18269-212515/yun_by_pighixxx-d6qvbq4.png) Yun pinout diagram.

Comment: I wired as described, (but I wired the 3.3v on the rc522 to the 3.3v on Yun, not the icsp pin because apparently the voltage isn't specified in [icsp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-system_programming) .) Unfortunately even after installing the library, successfully uploading their [example](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/MFRC522), it doesn't seem to do anything - only shows a red light on the device, and blank serial monitor when tag is right on it. I think there's a step missing somewhere here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues Thanks for help .However I made the  following connections then above mentioned

RC522 RFID borad     Arduino YUN  (as per the github example code dumpinfo)
chip select (nss ) - Pin 10 
Rst                - Pin 9

Link for Gihub RFID RC522
Hope it helps someone who is stuck